# How to make the div grow with its content?

Tags: html, css

I know there's millions of questions like that, but no approach really helps me. First my code and my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lunaetic/5dnuz6nq/1/) (very simplified because it's from GWT):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="inline minfirst">Password</div>
<div class="inline min">
    <div class="inline"><input type="text" class="text pwd" /></div>
    <div class="inline"><button class="toggleButton pwdToggle" /></div>
</div>
```

```
.row {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.inline {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.minfirst {
    min-width: 200px;
}

.inline.minfirst {
    font-size: 0.85em;
}

.min {
    min-width: 380px;
}

.text {
    border-radius: 22px;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
}

.pwdToggle {
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.pwd {
    height: 1.85em;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

.toggleButton {
    width: 65px;
    height: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

What I want to achieve is that the div with the input inside takes up the remaining space of the div with classes "inline" and "min" and the input should take all space inside of the div. But what happens now is that the input is bigger than its parent div and that makes everything behave weird.

Comment: Div automatically grow with its content unless you made the fixed height or width to the div.

Comment: Strangely enough it does not work in my case

Comment: Input elements has it default height. You change its height you can mention from css.

Comment: If you set the size of .pwd to auto, it fills the cell nicely... however, the table-cell divs does not fill the parent .row. Working on a solution to that one too :-)

Comment: It's right for them to not fill .row, so no solution needed there ^^ But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're well aware of `CSS` property `box-sizing: border-box;`.

you've given `padding` to your `input` field along with `width:100%` viz causing the extra `height` as well as `width` and i.e. why its bigger than its parent `div`.

Here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/5dnuz6nq/2/)
 I've edited please check.

[image]

Comment: Already tried it and it was still slightly bigger. And the strangest thing is that I have a lot more inputs in my actual project, also just like this one but without a button next to them. They work out fine with padding and everything.

Comment: @Lunaetic please check my answer I've edited, may be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The general problem is that you have table-cells without a table.
If you define the outer .row as a fixed table with 100% width you are on your way.

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5dnuz6nq/3/)

The new code for the .row is:

```
.row { display:table; table-layout: fixed; width:100%; }
```

Take a look :-)

Comment: Nice idea without the width of 100%, but I still have the problem that the two "inline" divs don't take up all the width that's available.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - with the above solution the <input> uses all available space - should it be shared between the <input> and <button>?